# Не получается встроить в страницу anchorjs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Друзья, решил встроить в страницу [anchorjs скрипт](http://bryanbraun.github.io/anchorjs/). Скачал сам скрипт. Скинул в папку /js. Подключил скрипт на странице строкой

```
<script src="js/anchor.js"></script>
```

Но дальше так и не понял как его подключить на самой странице. Все делаю по образцу со [страницы автора](https://jsfiddle.net/bryanbraun/x85hfvbk/). Результат - ноль.

Подскажите, что не так? Заранее благодарен.